# Running cmd as Administrator in PHP

Tags: php, iis-7, cmd, administrator, appcmd

Is there a way to run a CMD command as Administrator with PHP? I am trying to create a website on IIS7 using the appcmd.exe utility by running exec("%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD list sites") I get an error saying I don't have the right permissions but if I RDP and run the same command on CMD as an Administrator it works fine.

**Update:**

What am trying to accomplish is to automate website creation on IIS 7 using a web portal that I have been working on vs adding websites to the server manually

Comment: If PHP could do that easily, it'd be uninstalled from every Windows machine i've ever owned.  As would IIS.  And possibly Windows.  You're talking about a *huge* security hole here.  I (as admin!) can't even run an app as admin without that UAC box popping up, but your PHP code (running as NetworkService or whatever) can?  Nu-uh.

Comment: Try disabling anonymous authentication for your website. This should require you to login... login using AD credentials and see if the script works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a huge security risk, and I would advise against it, but for the sake of answering your question, you may be able to change the permissions on appcmd.exe in order to allow your IIS user to run it. Not sure if there are any external dependencies that would also need permission changes.

Again, though, this seems like not the greatest idea. Most of the time, programs require administrator privileges for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is write a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in another language to expose the results you need and then communicate with it locally over some other port.  Then install the service and have it run as administrator.